# passing arrays to a function in erlang

Tags: arrays, function, erlang, arguments

I am new to erlang programming and as a matter of fact no very experienced programmer. 
I need to pass an array to a function and then manipulate it.. however I have so far not be this what I found.

```
module(easy).
export([myfunction/1]).

myfunction([myarray]) ->
%% mycode.. hier I will need to do some stuff like getting the length of the array and I plan to   pearse it to list first and get the length. is that efficient? then need to loop through
```

the problem is that when I run the program like:

```
easy:myfunction([3,2,5]).
```

I get ** exception error: no function clause matching.

> How could I pass an array to a function.

Comment: I believe the problem here is *pattern matching* and that the pattern `[myarray]` does not fit the value `[3,2,5]`. `myfunction(myarray)` would fit, or `myfunction([a,b,c])`.

Comment: @deceze thanks a lot for your response. I did try myfunction(myarray).. but I got an error message. regarding myfunction([a,b,c]), I would like to have a random array size.. I do not want to limit the size of the array to any number. well at least a maxi of 10000

Comment: The Erlang documentation is extremely valuable but not very useful for learning the language. I encourage you to go to the website [Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content) which will help you all along your learning curve, covering the syntax, the concurrency, the application structure, the test and many other topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Hynek Vychodil says in his answer, there is no built-in array type in Erlang. Arrays do exist, in a sense, as you can get something that *behaves like* an (immutable) array using the [array](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/array.html) module.

In Erlang, an expression that begins with an opening bracket, such as `[1, 2, 3]`, denotes a list literal. While superficially similar, lists and arrays differ significantly. In particular, it is generally not possible to access an element in a list without first scanning all the preceding elements. *Changing* a list element involves **copying all preceding elements**. Consequently, applications that use lists as if they were arrays may suffer significant performance penalties.*

Now on to your code. The declaration:

```
myfunction([myarray]) ->
    %% ...
```

Introduces a function with a single clause that [matches](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions) lists containing the [atom](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id64134)`myarray`, and nothing else. This basically means that when you call `myfunction` with any other list, the Erlang interpreter will compare it to the list `[myarray]`. This comparison will fail. Since there is only one function clause, there are no further options to try. Consequently, the interpreter causes the process to exit with a `function_clause` error.

If, on the other hand, you called the function like this:

```
use_it() ->
    myfunction([myarray]).
```

The clause would match, and you would get no error. But it sounds to me like what you are trying to do is to have a function that accepts just any old list as its argument. In that case, you could try this:

```
myfunction(List) ->
    %% ...
```

The uppercase L is significant. As we've seen, an identifier beginning with a lowercase letter denotes an atom. Identifiers beginning with an uppercase letter or an underscore denote variables. If you want to do something with your list, perhaps take its length, you could add the following to the function body:

```
myfunction(List) ->
    length(List).
```

Observe that functions in Erlang implicitly return the value of the last expression in the body.

The take home is that functions in Erlang behave quite differently from what you may be used to from other programming languages. I encourage you to read the material I linked above and to play around with the concept of pattern matching in function clauses in order to deepen your understanding of Erlang.

(*) Note that the above pertains to Erlang and certain other functional languages only. The concept of a list is not well defined in general, and may be used to refer to a data structure that behaves more like an array. Python is perhaps the canonical example.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there is not array data type in Erlang except you mean data structure used by a module [`array`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/array.html). There is a data type list which is called list for a good reason. Because it is a list not array. The second thing is, variables in Erlang must start with capital letter. So your code should be

```
-module(easy).
-export([myfunction/1]).

myfunction(MyList) ->
    length(MyList).
```

And then you can pass list to it

```
1> easy:myfunction([3,2,5]).
3
2>
```

The closest data type to array in Erlang is tuple which is denoted by `{}`. So your code can look like:

```
myfunction(MyTuple) ->
    tuple_size(MyTuple).
```

and used by

```
1> easy:myfunction({3,2,5}).
3
2>
```

Please read [introduction](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/seq_prog.html) from manual to get grasp of basic principles of Erlang.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually got confused with [array](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/array.html) described in Erlang documentation. but then got stacked with how to get the sized of the "array", that is when the idea to pearse it to list come about. now my question right is why is this data structure called **array** then if it no array? what is its use in this case.